# Como adicionar um `ul` em um elemento `li` HTML via código c#?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net

Vou ter uma lista com vários clientes, e queria adicionar esses clientes em um `ul` do elemento `li` no HTML, tem como adicionar esses cliente dinamicamente (pois cada pesquisa realizada no sistema poderá trazer um número de clientes) via código c# ?

Comment: Tem sim, teu projeto é MVC ou WebForms?

Comment: Ele esta em WebForms

Comment: Você está usando Razor ou aspx?

Comment: Não estou usando não

Comment: Cara desculpa, ontem eu já estava de saída da empresa, vou tentar fazer hoje, assim que eu tentar eu posto aqui se eu consegui ou não, obrigado !

Comment: Consegui fazer, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa forma (dentro do seu arquivo **.aspx**):

```
<ul>
    <% var numeros = new List<int>{1, 2, 3};
       foreach (int i in lista)
        {
            %> <li> <%: i %> </li>
     <% } %>
</ul>
```

Neste exemplo, estou criando uma lista com três números e imprimindo cada um deles na tag `<li>`.

A única coisa que você precisa adaptar é colocar a sua lista no `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

Segue um outro exemplo que pode ser feito pelo **.aspx.cs(CodeBehind)**

```
using System.IO;   

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Cliente> lstCliente = new List<Cliente>
        {
            new Cliente{ Id = 1, Nome = "Cliente1"},
            new Cliente{ Id = 2, Nome = "Cliente2"},
            new Cliente{ Id = 3, Nome = "Cliente3"},
            new Cliente{ Id = 4, Nome = "Cliente4"},
        };

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

        htmlWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul); //Cria a tag ul

        foreach (Cliente cliente in lstCliente)
        {
            htmlWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Li); //Cria tag li
            htmlWriter.Write(string.Concat(cliente.Id, ": ", cliente.Nome));
            htmlWriter.RenderEndTag(); //Fecha tag li
        }                       

        htmlWriter.RenderEndTag(); Fecha tag ul

        ltListaClientes.Text = stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

No **.aspx** eu adicionei um literal para receber a lista

```
<asp:Literal id="ltListaClientes" runat="server" />
```